# WPF-Xaml IconSource

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0

I am attempting to include an IconSource in my XAML file but upon debugging, VS2013 throws a "cannot locate..." error.  I am certain that I am making a stupid mistake somewhere but I have spent two days attempting to track it down to no avail.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="TB_Icon.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <tb:TaskbarIcon
            IconSource=" /Codebank/Companion_Replacement/WPF_Taskbar/TB_Icon/TB_Icon/Resources/L1.ico"
            ToolTip="Click the item..."/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Directory Structure
C:\Codebank\Companion_Replacement\WPF_Taskbar\TB_Icon\TB_Icon\L1.ico

VS Solution Explorer
Solution TB_Icon
   TB_Icon
     Resources
       L1.ico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Pack URIs in WPF

In this case like : `pack://application:,,,/TB_Icon/TB_Icon/L1.ico`

[Pack URIs in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx)

[Icon Url](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.window.icon(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: This works well except that the icon I am attempting to view (in debug anyway) is a system icon.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a space at the beginning of the path. Testing on my system if I put a space it says `cannot find c:\thing.ico`, and even if I put thing.ico directly at the c:\ it doesn't find it. You either need to type in the drive letter like this (without a space):

`IconSource="C:/Codebank/Companion_Replacement/WPF_Taskbar/TB_Icon/TB_Icon/Resources/L1.ico"`

Or get rid of the space and put the icon in the correct relative path, such as: `C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WpfApplication1\Codebank\Companion_Replacement\WPF_Taskbar\TB_Icon\TB_Icon\Resources\L1.ico`, then you should be able to type in `IconSource="/Codebank/Companion_Replacement/WPF_Taskbar/TB_Icon/TB_Icon/Resources/L1.ico"` (no space)

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions.   I went with the suggestion from jophy job.